# How do you specify different authentication methods on different actions in a single controller?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

How do indicate that a particular action uses Basic Auth while another uses Bearer Token?

Essentially what I have is a controller with 3 actions:

```
GET GetPublicKey - No Auth
POST GenerateToken - Basic Auth
POST RefreshToken - Bearer Token
```

What I do not want to be doing is validating user credentials when `GetPublicKey` or `RefreshToken` is called, because (as per my earlier question), whenever user validation happens, the `UserRepository` is re-initialised, which necessitates reading data from the database.

The use of `Policies` isn't what I need, as that is role assignment. In my case there are no roles.

I tried using `[AllowAnonymous]` on the `GetPublicKey` action but that still goes through the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` in my `BasicAuthenticationHandler`, which is triggering a database read.

Comment: Could you post the program.cs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with below program.cs. Add different `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "xxx")]`attribute on top of controller method works in this scenrio. When there is no whole project authorize policy,only choosen authenticate method is triggered. So you don't need `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. And without it, `HandleAuthenticateAsync` is certainly not triggered.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using WebApplication8;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", opts => { });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                     .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                     {
                         options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

                         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                         {
                             ValidateAudience = false
                         };
                     });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Add attribute like below

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test1")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
        public string test1()
        {
            return "test1-bear";
        }

        [HttpGet("test2")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]
        public string test2()
        {
            return "test2-basic";
        }

        [HttpGet("test3")]
        public string test3()
        {
            return "test2-No auth";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, although I've yet to get the token to work. But that's a different matter.

Comment: OK. I'm stuck. The "test1-bear" never gets shown. Postman always shows **401 Unauthorized** when I call the `test1` action. I'm using the JWT created by `dotnet user-jwts create` for my project.

Comment: @SiBrit I used identiy server 4 client credential flow to generate token and works. I haven't used `dotnet user-jwts create` before but i will try testing.

Comment: Thank you. As you know, the `BasicAuthenticationHandler` referenced in the `Program.cs` is a descendant class from `AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>` in which you override the `Task<AuthenticateResult>` method with your own authentication process. Is there something like this for JWT bearer, potentially derived from `JwtBearerHandler`?

Comment: @SiBrit https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-jwt-in-net-core-api/ This may help.